# How to increment Row inside echo

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I would like to know if there is away and if this is valid programming to increment the value of array inside echo. Example code is:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number; $x++) {
   echo"<td>".(round(($row['day_1'])/3600))."</td>";
}
```

Where I would like to display `$row['day_1']`, `$row['day_2']`, `$row['day_3']` etc. if there is no way this to be achieved, is there a way to increment the same predefined array with the results of $row like

```
$time_01[0] = $row['day_1'];
$time_01[1] = $row['day_2'];
```

So after that to loop through the time_01[] array ?

Comment: Are you looking for `$row['day_' . $x]` ? I'm not so sure I got it from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Least amount of changes: Use the `$x` you already have:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number; $x++) {
   echo"<td>".(round(($row["day_$x"])/3600))."</td>";
}
```

or

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number; $x++) {
   echo"<td>".(round(($row['day_' . $x])/3600))."</td>";
}
```

or if you want to put it in another array first, for whatever reason:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number; $x++) {
   $time_01[] = $row['day_' . $x];
}
```

This really is basic stuff by the way. I do recommend that you follow some basic tutorials about variables, expressions, string concatenation and more.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted . Thank you !